# Rails Testing - Break code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I am writing test cases for ROR. The code to test one model/controller is too much . Is there anyway to break the file in different files for testing the same model/controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can split up tests into different files. I believe test::unit requires files to be `*_test.rb`.

So say you had a test file for a User model. You could have your tests broken up like:

```
user_validations_test.rb
user_login_test.rb
...
```

I know you're using test::unit but, same thing goes with RSpec, you can break up your tests into `*_spec.rb` files.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using rspec for testing, you can simply add more than one file describing the same class. It might be reasonable to create in `spec/` directory matching subdirectory, and place all spec files in there.

Comment: I am using the default test library test::unit and not RSPEC, Is it possible to do it with the default lib ?

Comment: extract testing behavior into modules?